Many contradictory results for a single integral
I am interested in solving the integral $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} dx \frac{e^{i a x^2}}{(x - b - ic)^d(x - b + ic)^d}
$$
for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$. As an early step, I have asked Mathematica to exactly evalute the special case $a = 1,d = 2$ and restricting to $b,c > 0$. In the WolframCloud enviroment I asked for
Integrate[Exp[-I*x^2]/ ((x-b-I*c)^2(x-b+I*c)^2),{x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions->c>0&&b>0]

(apologies if this isn't a standard way to typeset a Mathematica command) and Mathematica happily returned 0. This was a little surprising and I couldn't see a good symmetry or contour argument to support it, so I tried again with $b,c$ explicitly set to specific numbers.
Integrate[Exp[-I*x^2]/ ((x-4-I*7)^2(x-4+I*7)^2),{x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

and Mathematica returned an ugly mess of MeijerG functions. When I asked Mathematica to give me the numerical value of this result with
N[%]

it returned $-7.16557 \times 10^{10} + i 1.7494 \times 10^{11}$, which is decidedly not 0 as Mathematica claimed in the general case. To settle the matter (does this integral vanish exactly, or is it secretly a complex number with components on the order of $10^{11}$ for reasonably small parameter values?) I tried directly numerical integration, for good measure using a nice large working precision as
NIntegrate[Exp[-I*x^2]/ ((x-4-I*7)^2(x-4+I*7)^2),{x, -Infinity, Infinity},WorkingPrecision->30]

but this returned a number around $2.94682 \times 10^{-4} + i 2.99022 \times 10^{-4}$. Increasing the working precision adds more decimals but doesn't make this number tend to 0, and messing around with large but finite integration bounds has a similar effect.
What's going on? If the integral is actually 0, it's very surprising that exact integration should yield an analytic expression that Mathematica thinks is on the order of $10^{11}$, and in the context of my present work (this integral comes from an S-matrix calculation) it would be really weird for the integral to vanish. On the other hand, if it isn't exactly 0, there would seem to be a major bug in Mathematica's exact integration library.

It cannot be zero for those assumptions because then it is an absolute value to a power d since the factors are conjugates. Also, use N[...,20] to get an accurate numeric evaluation of the MeijerG stuff.

Agreed on your first point. On the second point, interestingly for higher precision with N[...,prec] evaluating the MeijerG expression converges on a number around $(4+i) \times 10^{-4}$, which is yet another number in disagreement with the values I've found.

For $d=2$
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-i a x^2}}{(-A+x)^2 (-B+x)^2} \, dx=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \mathcal{L}_a\left[e^{-i a x^2} (-A+x)^{-2} (-B+x)^{-2}\right](s) \,
   dx\right](a)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{(-A+x)^2 (-B+x)^2 \left(s+i x^2\right)} \, dx\right](a)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \pi
    \left((-2+2 i) A \left(B^2-2 \sqrt[4]{-1} B \sqrt{s}+i s\right) \sqrt{s}+s \left(\sqrt{2} B^2-(2+2 i) B \sqrt{s}+i \sqrt{2} s\right)+A^2 \left(-i \sqrt{2} B^2-(2-2 i) B \sqrt{s}+\sqrt{2}
   s\right)\right)}{\sqrt{s} \left(i A^2+s\right)^2 \left(i B^2+s\right)^2}\right](a)=\\\frac{2 e^{-i a \left(A^2+B^2\right)} \left((-1-i) \sqrt{a} (A-B) e^{i a \left(A^2+B^2\right)} \sqrt{2 \pi }+(-i+a
   A (A-B)) e^{i a B^2} \pi  \left(1+\text{erf}\left((-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{a} A\right)\right)+(i+a (A-B) B) e^{i a A^2} \pi  \left(1+\text{erf}\left((-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{a} B\right)\right)\right)}{(A-B)^3}$
Code to get solution:
InverseLaplaceTransform[Integrate[
LaplaceTransform[E^(-I a x^2) (-A + x)^-d (-B + x)^-d /. d -> 2, 
 a, s], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}][[1]], s, a] // FullSimplify
(*Solution*)

We can check:
F1[a_, A_, B_] := NIntegrate[
E^(-I a x^2)/((-A + x)^2 (-B + x)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 50];
F2[a_, A_, B_] := 
N[(2 E^(-I a (A^2 + B^2)) ((-1 - I) Sqrt[a] (A - B) E^(
   I a (A^2 + B^2)) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + (-I + a A (A - B)) E^(
   I a B^2) \[Pi] (1 + Erf[(-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[a] A]) + (I + 
     a (A - B) B) E^(
   I a A^2) \[Pi] (1 + Erf[(-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[a] B])))/(A - B)^3, 30];

F2[1, 4 + 7*I, 4 - 7*I]
(*0.000294681507989332117712931911612 - 0.000299021779245319327384604740202 I *)

F1[1, 4 + 7*I, 4 - 7*I] - F2[1, 4 + 7*I, 4 - 7*I]
(*2.12890009*10^-25 + 1.27636263*10^-25 I*)

Generealization for: $d>0$
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-i a x^2}}{(-A+x)^d (-B+x)^d} \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{(-1)^m (i a)^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m}{2}} (-A)^{-d-m} (-B)^{-d} d \Gamma \left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right) \Gamma (2
   d+m) \, _2F_1\left(d,-m;2 d;1-\frac{A}{B}\right)}{m! \Gamma (1+2 d)}+\frac{(-1)^m (i a)^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m}{2}} A^d \left(-A^2\right)^{-d} (-B)^{-d} B^{-m} \Gamma \left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right) \Gamma (d+m) \,
   _2F_1\left(d,-m;1-d-m;\frac{B}{A}\right)}{2 m! \Gamma (d)}\right)$
 F5[a_, d_, A_, B_] := NIntegrate[
 E^(-I a x^2)/((-A + x)^d (-B + x)^d), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 20]; 
 F6[a_, d_, A_, B_] := N[Sum[((-1)^
 m (I a)^(-(1/2) - m/2) (-A)^(-d - m) (-B)^-d d Gamma[(1 + m)/
  2] Gamma[2 d + m] Hypergeometric2F1[d, -m, 2 d, 1 - A/B])/(
 m! Gamma[1 + 2 d]) + ((-1)^m (I a)^(-(1/2) - m/2) A^
 d (-A^2)^-d (-B)^-d B^-m Gamma[(1 + m)/2] Gamma[
  d + m] Hypergeometric2F1[d, -m, 1 - d - m, B/A])/(
 2 m! Gamma[d]), {m, 0, 200}], 20];

 F5[1, 3, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I] - F6[1, 3, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I](*For d = 3 *)
 (*-1.6156634*10^-18 + 1.7169275*10^-18 I*)

UPDATE 23.12.2024
Integral can be expressed by double series and series can be expressed by Srivastava-Daoust multivariable hypergeometric function.
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-i a x^2}}{(-A+x)^d (-B+x)^d} \, dx=\\-\frac{i \sqrt{i a} (-A)^{-d} (-B)^{-d} \sqrt{\pi } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}} (d)_m (d)_n \left(\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i a} A}\right)^m \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i a} B}\right)^n\right)}{n! m!}}{2 a}-\frac{i \sqrt{i a} (-A)^{-d}
   (-B)^{-d} \sqrt{\pi } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}} (d)_m (d)_n \left(\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{i a} A}\right)^m \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{i
   a} B}\right)^n\right)}{n! m!}}{2 a}=\color{red}{\text{ Srivastava-Daoust multivariable hypergeometric function}}$
for: $d>0$
We can check:
F5[a_, d_, A_, B_] := NIntegrate[
E^(-I a x^2)/((-A + x)^d (-B + x)^d), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 20]; 
G5[a_, d_, A_, B_, M_] := -I Sqrt[I a] (-A)^-d (-B)^-d Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(2 a)*
Sum[ Pochhammer[1/2, m/2 + n/2] Pochhammer[d, m] Pochhammer[d, 
  n]*((1/(Sqrt[I a] A))^m (1/(Sqrt[I a] B))^n)/(n! m!) , {m, 0, 
 M}, {n, 0, M}] - 
I Sqrt[I a] (-A)^-d (-B)^-d Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(2 a)*
Sum[ Pochhammer[1/2, m/2 + n/2] Pochhammer[d, m] Pochhammer[d, 
  n]*((-(1/(Sqrt[I a] A)))^m (-(1/(Sqrt[I a] B)))^n)/(n! m!) , 
{m, 0, M}, {n, 0, M}];

{F5[1, 2, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I] - N[G5[1, 2, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I, 100], 20]}
(*{-3.0213518*10^-16 + 8.4083801*10^-16 I}*)


A spot on the Sun: F6[1, 3, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I] // Timing results in {0.890625,   4.4690840455125299509*10^-6 - 4.6730083678839851760*10^-6 I} and F5[1, 3, 4 + 7 I, 4 - 7 I] // Timing results in {0.09375,     4.4690840455109142875*10^-6 - 4.6730083678822682485*10^-6 I}}.

It is not a good practice to edit an answer, not indicating changes. There was  {n,0,20} in F6 and the timing in the above comment of me is for that range in the sum.

@user64494 Are you hallucinating, click "edited 1 hour ago" and see what I edited?

@MariushIwaniuk: You are right. Sorry for my previous comment. The timing with {n,0,20} is {0.015625,   4.4690840455512364677*10^-6 - 4.6730083678412254913*10^-6 I}. I think the game (i.e. the analytic form) is not worth the candle.

In any case, the integral under consideration does not equal zero.
Indeed,
ComplexExpand[((x - b - I*c)^2*(x - b + I*c)^2)] // Factor


(b^2 + c^2 - 2 b x + x^2)^2

and
b = 1; c = 1; NIntegrate[Exp[-I*x^2]/(b^2 + c^2 - 2 b x + x^2)^2,
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]


0.50603 - 0.690537 I

In my personal opinion, any analytic expression for the integral under consideration is useless.

b = 4; c = 7; NIntegrate[  Exp[-I*x^2]/(b^2 + c^2 - 2 b x + x^2)^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},   Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"] results in 0.000294681 - 0.000299022 I.

Yes, I'm also quite sure the integral doesn't actually vanish. But in that case, what's wrong with the way I used Integrate? Surely it's not meant to fail this badly and so quietly and confidently.

@mpc: I think this is a bug of Integrate. BTW, for b = 4; c = 7;  Rubi's Int[Exp[-I*x^2]/(b^2 + c^2 - 2 b x + x^2)^2, x] outputs -(E^(-I x^2)/(98 ((8 + 14 I) - 2 x))) + E^(-I x^2)/(  98 ((-8 + 14 I) + 2 x)) +   1/98 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[\[Pi]]    Erf[(-1)^(1/4) x] + (1/7 - (55 I)/686) Int[    E^(-I x^2)/((8 + 14 I) - 2 x), x] + (1/7 + (57 I)/686) Int[    E^(-I x^2)/((-8 + 14 I) + 2 x), x].
